# Excel 2016 copy everything after the first character which repeats itself in excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, extract

I have a sequence of numbers of each line, and I would like to `copy and paste` the last numbers of each sequence beside the that cell. The sequence contains two dots, and i would like to copy and paste everything which appears after the first dot.

Check the below sample:

```
Sequence: "12345678.11.11"
Result should be: "11.11"
```

in a different cell.

Any idea on this? Either `VBA` coding or normal excel sheet coding would be fine. I would insert in into a `VBA` later in.

THanks for your help.
Regards,
Tibor

Comment: Hey! Thanks for both of you. Both of the answers are very valuable.
What if the range is always changing? How can I solve this with a loop? I want the loop run as long as it finds data in that specific column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this (commented) code

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim cell As Range
    With Worksheets("MySheet") '<--| change "MySheet" to your actual sheet name
        For Each cell In .Range("A1:A10").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants) '<--| change "A1:A10" to your actual range with dotted numbers
            cell.Offset(, 1) = "'" & Split(cell, ".")(1) & "." & Split(cell, ".")(2)'<--| write last to dotted numbers in cell adjacent to current one
        Next cell
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your answers is very valuable. What if the range is always changing? How can I solve this with a loop? I want the loop run as long as it finds data in that specific column?

Comment: I tried with this. :Sheets("KKK").Range("AF" & j) = "=RIGHT(KKK!R4C32,LEN(AE)-FIND(".",AE))"

when I give this to the VBA, it gives back a compile error for the dot after FIND. It would take out from AF column the info, and would put into AE column. It is put into a loop, and ends when there is no more data.

Comment: The loop is already there in `For Each cell In...` . And `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)` takes already care to consider not empty cells only in range it's being called upon. So you just change `.Range("A1:A10")` to `.Columns("AF")` and you are done

Answer (score 2):

If its always the first full stop, then you can use the following function in the spreadsheet instead of VBA (example on cell A1):

```
=RIGHT(A1, (LEN(A1) - FIND(".", A1)))
```

Comment: THanks, it works well!!! I will try to figure out in VBA as well. Lets see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't suggest VBA since worksheets functions are great for this kind of thing:

```
=MID(A1,FIND(".",A1)+1,100))
=REPLACE(A1,1,FIND(".",A1),"")
```

... are just two examples that haven't already been given

---

If you want to give VBA a go, add this function to a module in your VBA editor:

```
Function GetRight(rng As Range)
    GetRight = Right(rng.value, Len(rng.value) - InStr(rng.value, "."))
End Function
```

... and then simply use the function on the worksheet like this

```
=GetRight(A1)
```

You can drag this along and down like a normal function

**EDIT**

Here is the full code if you want VBA to find all values in column A and return required output to column B

```
Sub GetAllRight()
    Dim rng As Range, r As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set rng = .Range(.Range("A1"), .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    End With
    For Each r In rng
        r.Offset(0, 1).Value = GetRight(r)
    Next r
End Sub

Function GetRight(rng As Range) As String
    GetRight = Right(rng.Value, Len(rng.Value) - InStr(rng.Value, "."))
End Function
```